# Calculate bottom 10% and top 10% values from quartile values

Tags: c#, math, statistics

**UPDATE**: I found the following [C# Library](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Statistics&referringTitle=Documentation), and it is perfect for what I need.

==============================================================

So I have a collection of data points, for example: 4, 5, 2, 3, 15, 3, 3, 5
I have then calculated out the upper (Q2) and lower quartiles (Q1), which are 5 and 3 respectively.

Because of the quartiles I can reference from the lowest number to the Q1 to target the low 25% and then from the hightest value to Q2 to target the top 25%. Because I now have Q1 and Q2 I can also target the inner 50% of the values.

With this information I want to be able to figure our where 90% of the data falls and I haven't been able to find anywhere online that references getting any other percentages other than 25%.

If it helps, my server side language that I am doing these computations on is C# with .NET 4.5, but I am wanting to know the math behind it more than the programmatic way to accomplish it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Hopefully what I have written is clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Specialized_quantiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask with specific reference to the mathematics, so I won't include any code.

The first thing to do is construct the knots for a quantile function (which is a plot with probability on the x axis and value on the y axis). Do this by sorting the values to yield, in your case, this table:

```
Probability   Value
1/8           2
4/8           3
5/8           4
7/8           5
8/8          15
```

Then construct a **monotone cubic spline interpolator** which passes through these points. You use a montotone cubic spline since (1) the quantile function can never have a negative slope and (2) it must be continuous to at least first order (as the reciprocal of the first derivative of the quantile function is the probability density function).

You can then use the interpolator to lookup other values. e.g. lookup the 90% interpolator value to give the result for which you have a 90% chance of attaining.

Of course, the intermediate values between the knots are inferred from the data and is an approximation.

Comment: Would'nt the probability of getting 3 be 3/8, 4 be 1/8, 5 be 2/8, 2 be 1/8, 15 be 1/8?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clarification. I'm just working through this to determine if it's what I need. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: PS We do this kind of thing in financial mathematics all the time: it does take some time to get to grips with the concepts. By the way, you really need more sample points for the interpolation to make much sense.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too used to this type of thing but I love learning new stuff, so this is great. I was actually thinking that myself, I have 8 data points and having a band on the chart to show where 50% of them fall is good, but I'm not sure if 90% is necessary.

Comment: So I'm looking through how to do the math for the spline, and man is it intense. I'm not really sure where to start. Given the above table you provided, which formula should I be using to place that data. I'm looking at the [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline](wiki page) Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Practitioners use canned maths libraries for this stuff. Have a google for such a library in C#.